solana account size
In my test:

token account: 165 bytes, need rent 0.00203928 sol
account: 0 byte, no need rent.

Questions:

Can you confirm that normal account's size is 0 byte?

Is it because the sol balance is stored outside the data field, thus no byte is taken?


If so, is there any case that can cause the data become non-zero ?



By default, an account has no data stored, so its size is 0 bytes, but rent is required if you want the account to hold a SOL balance:

$ solana rent 0
Rent-exempt minimum: 0.00089088 SOL

This is because an account with no data but with some SOL still takes up space in the accounts database, and that must be paid for.

An account will allocate space by calling the allocate instruction on the system program, which also requires a signature from the account.

